# Getting NULL on select option populated with JSON containing special characters

Tags: php, json, select, special-characters, populate

I'm populating a `<select>` from JSON.
The problem is that when the value that comes from the mysql database has special characters such as `Ñ` or `Á`, I'm getting `NULL` in the `<select>`.

Here's my JS code:

```
function llenarEspecialidad()
{
    var espec =  $("#comboEspecialidad").val();
    var $select = $("#comboMedicoIC");
    document.formAgregar.comboMedicoIC.length=0;
    document.formAgregar.comboMedicoIC.options[0] = new Option("Seleccione","0","defaultSelected","");

    $(function(){
        var items="";
        $.getJSON("internacionLlenarMedicos.php?&idEspecialidad="+espec,function(data){
            $.each(data,function(index,item) 
            {
                items+="<option value='"+item.idMedico+"'>"+item.Medico+"</option>";
            });
            $select.append(items);
        });
    });
};
```

And here's the server side code:

```
$espe = $_REQUEST["idEspecialidad"];
$sql_depto = "SELECT idMedico, CONCAT(apellido, ',', nombre) As Medico FROM medicos where activo is Null and ( (".$espe."=0) or (".$espe."<>0 and ".$espe." = idEspecialidad  ) ) ORDER by apellido ASC";
$rs_depto = mysql_query($sql_depto, $conexion);
$data = array();
while($row_depto = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_depto))
    $data[] =$row_depto;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Both PHP files are ANSI encoded, I can not encode in UTF-8 because if I do, then other problems arise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) only works properly with utf-8 strings, otherwise it will return null, so you have to encode it.

So you can try [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

```
// this is just an example for one dimensional arrays
$your_array = array_map( "utf8_decode" , $your_array );
```

if this is not working you have to check your DB char set or collation and use [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: And what would be the proper collation ? and the character set ? Thank you

Comment: @martin.softpro There is no proper collation. It depends on a lot. But if you develop something from scratch, you can simply use UTF-8, the collation I prefer is utf8_general_ci.